# MacOS zip folder error code -36/ couldn't communicate with a helper application

Tags: finder, copy-paste, zip

I want to zip a folder (any folder). When I try to do so I get:

> couldn't communicate with a helper application

Also, when I try to copy any folder I get exactly the following:

> Finder can’t complete the operation because some data in “” can’t be read or written. (Error code -36)

I've tried

- restarting finder
- restarting the computer
- shutting down and then re-opening the computer
- checking file and folder permissions (both read and write)
- showing hidden files, none show up
- running `dot_clean` command

Both errors persist and only apply to folders (copying/zipping files is fine). I have no idea/direction on how to solve them. I can only think it could be related to having recently changed my Apple ID password. The Terminal `zip` command works fine on both folders and files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to have solved itself after I loaded a time machine backup i had from two weeks ago. I have not found the cause but it seems to work fine for now.

Answer (score 0):

On my end this issue still persists and has not solved itself. I have changed my macOS username at one point and I cannot remember for sure if this issue started occurring after that change.

Workarounds I have implemented since to still be able to compress things are:

1. Using [`Keka`](https://www.keka.io/en/)
2. Using `zip` from the command-line

I would be grateful to anyone with a solution to the root-cause of this problem that could contribute it to this thread.