# Unable to copy or compress folders in actively synching iCloud Documents and Desktop folders

Tags: icloud, finder, folders, archive-utility

I am using a 2022 Mac Studio M1 Ultra running Ventura 13.2.1, however I have been experiencing this issue since Monterey.

I can't **compress** or **copy/duplicate** folders when the parent folder is synching to iCloud (i.e. there is a dotted-line cloud symbol to the right of the folder name in Finder), however *individual files* do not pose this problem and both functions work normally as soon as the parent folder is fully synched to iCloud.

I have tried all the same things as this user brought up in a similar post [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/445000/cannot-copy-folder-in-documents-and-desktop-folders-linked-with-icloud-drive), however I have narrowed it down further to only be an issue when the folder is actively synching.

[This person](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/454750/macos-zip-folder-error-code-36-couldnt-communicate-with-a-helper-application) seems to have solved the issue by reverting to a previous Time Machine backup, however I use Backblaze rather than Time Machine so this was not a workaround for me.

### **The Problems**

1. When I try to zip a folder inside of a folder that is currently
   synching to iCloud I receive an error from Archive Utility that
   reads: "Couldn't communicate with a helper application."
   [image: Screenshot of Archive Utility Error Message]
2. When I try to duplicate or copy a folder to or from a currently
   synching iCloud folder I receive an error that reads "The Finder
   can’t complete the operation because some data in “” can’t be read
   or written. (Error code -36)"[image: Screenshot of Finder Error Message]

Comment: What are you paying BackBlaze for, if you can't restore your data?

Comment: Backblaze restores files but it doesn't back up your entire OS configuration like Time Machine does. This appears to be an iCloud configuration issue, not a corrupt or missing file issue.

Comment: I have *exactly* the same issue. I don't use BackBlaze, so doesn't appear to be related to that. I tried everything, including the suggestions in the posts you linked. I'm not in the position though to revert to an old TimeMachine backup..

Comment: Will keep monitor this post to see if someone found a solution. This is extremely annoying. I'm now zipping folders through the Terminal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For those with this issue and no available time machine backup:
I was getting this error when trying to compress or move folders stored in iCloud. Additionally, my iCloud folders all had the cloud icon indicating they were syncing but they would never finish syncing.

Here are the steps that worked for me:

1. Go to System Settings>AppleId>iCloud>iCloudDrive.
2. Uncheck "Sync this Mac" and "Desktop & Documents Folders".

[image: Apple iCoud Drive Warning]

Note: the warnings mean you won't be able to access iCloudDive/documents while these options are unchecked. Once rechecked all data is again available. But to be safe you can choose to make copy first.

3. Restart Mac.
4. Go back to ystem Settings>AppleId>iCloud>iCloudDrive.
5. Recheck "Sync this Mac" and "Desktop & Documents Folders".
6. Restart Mac.

The above steps reportedly work for some but not me. So check at this point to see if you can compress or move iCloud Folders.
If not, continue to terminal to reprioritize the iCloud upload process:

[image: update process priority in terminal]

1. Open terminal app (tap cmd+spacebar then type terminal in the search bar)
2. Get the PID (Process ID) of your iCloud sync process (called Bird)

   ```
   ps aux|grep bird
   ```
3. Find the current priority for the bird process using the PID from previous step (in this example my PID is 2547, yours will be different)

   ```
   ps -fl -c 2547
   ```
4. Change the current priority (enter admin password if requested)

   ```
   sudo renice -n -3 -p 2547
   ```

Note: Lower the priority values are handled first in queue and lowest possible value is -20. Changing the priority this way adds your input priority number to the existing value. For ex: if current process priority is -8 and -3 is input into the renice cmd the resulting priority will be -11.

5. Confirm that priority has been successfully changed

   ```
    ps -fl -c 2547
   ```
6. Restart Mac
7. Check that iCloud Drive no longer has cloud icon

If all worked out right you should be able to move or compress folders as you please now.

Comment: This solved my problem! Simply turning off my iCloud drive sync and then back on again after a restart as you suggested seems to have completely cleared the issue. I didn't have to go quite as far with the terminal commands thankfully. I do have quite a bit synched to my desktop, so it took a couple hours to redownload everything after turning it off, but all is back as it should be and the zipping and copying functions have returned to normal.